# CSS: :hover on element and target another

Tags: css

let's consider we have the following code:

```
<div class="post wrapper">
    <div class="post title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="post thumb"> // This has the post thumb set as background image
        <div class="post overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That with some extra CSS will result in:

[image]

If I want to get a nice effect when the user has the mouse the image I can do;

```
div.post.overlay:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

**Now**, the `:hover` effect will not work if the user places the mouse on the `Title` text / white box. To get around this I'm using:

```
div.post.wrapper:hover div.post.overlay { // => note where :hover is
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

**Is this valid CSS? Will it work reliable across browsers?** Is it okay to call `:hover` on the `wrapper` and then set the `background-color` on the `overlay`. It seems to work under Google Chrome and Safari.

Thank you.

Comment: yes, it is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **perfectly okay**. As long as the `div.post.overlay` is inside the `div.post.wrapper`, when you hover over the `div.post.wrapper`, the `div.post.overlay` gets the styles applied. This is valid in all browsers and it's a normal descendant selector.

Comment: Uh what? div.post.overlay is inside the div.post.wrapper?

Comment: @Highdef Yep, it's the grandchild I suppose. Check the OP's HTML code. ps: This is not child or direct descendant selector.

Comment: Oh, right just noticed that but it isn't necessary that the hover selector would only work if the overlay is inside. If the overlay's outside you can still make it work (sibling selectors).

Comment: @Highdef Just telling them for the current situation boss... :)

Comment: Thank you all for the tips!